# remove sudo access on beaglebone black

Tags: debian, root, beagleboneblack

I have a beaglebone black with Debian Image 2016-05-13.
I need to remove sudo access from 'debian' user.

I've already tried `sudo gpasswd -d debian sudo` and `sudo deluser debian sudo`, but when I try `sudo su` I still get into root.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simple matter of removing the offending user from the sudoers configuration file. Have a look at the text file at "/etc/sudoers" and remove the entry that begins with the username you want to remove access from. If you dont find it in there, also look at the text files in the /etc/sudoers.d directory. It is also possible (I dont know the default setup and the BBB as it has been a while) that the sudo access is simply granted to everyone, if this is the case, one of the files mentioned above will start with "ALL" and you may want to change "ALL" to the name of a user that retains sudo privileges.